# How to install deb package when it is extracted to a folder

Tags: apt, dpkg

I'm extracting a deb file into a directory with this command:

```
dpkg-deb -R xxx.deb ./theFolder
```

I'm changing postinst file to make installations proper to docker (systemctl start and daemon-reload is interrupting the installation when docker build).

But making this folder to deb file again with this command is taking too long:

```
dpkg-deb -b ./theFolder xxx_1.deb
```

And then installing the deb file with this command:

```
dpkg -i xxx_1.deb
```

Is there any way to install deb package without building another deb file, directly from theFolder?

Answer (score 1):

No. Package can only be installed from .deb archives. If the repacking is taking too long, perhaps you could use a quicker compressor than the default, via the `-Z` option, such as `gzip` or `none` with the latter being the quickest. :)